# How can generate file.go with protoc (GRPC)?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have calculator.proto in folder calc like this:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package calc;

option go_package = "learn_grpc_datnd";

service CalculatorService {
    
}
```

When I run `protoc --go-gprc_out=.; calc/calculator.proto` It shows error

```
Missing input file.
calc/calculator.proto: line 1: syntax: command not found
calc/calculator.proto: line 3: package: command not found
calc/calculator.proto: line 5: option: command not found
CalculatorService: unrecognized service
calc/calculator.proto: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
calc/calculator.proto: line 9: `} '
```

Why? I had already install all necessary package.

Comment: Remove or escape the semicolon.

Comment: @Peter I did. It shows :protoc-gen-go-gprc: program not found or is not executable
--go-gprc_out: protoc-gen-go-gprc: Plugin failed with status code 1.

Comment: Then you have not installed the Go plugin for protoc correctly.

Comment: The [quick start](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/go/quickstart/) explains how to install the necessary tools (and mentions the need to update your `path`).

Answer (score -1):

You need to make the following changes in your proto

```
option go_package = "./learn_grpc_datnd";
```

Then use this command to generate files.

```
protoc --go_out=paths=source_relative:./ --go-grpc_out=paths=source_relative:./ file.proto
```